# FastAPI is masking Apache2 inside Docker

Tags: apache-2.4, docker, reverse-proxy, docker-compose

I setup a webserver and a FastAPI in a single docker container.
Here are the relevant parts of the Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu/apache2:2.4-22.04_beta
[...]
# Apache conf
RUN echo '<VirtualHost *:80>\n\
            DocumentRoot /var/www/html\n\
            <Directory "/var/www/html">\n\
                Options MultiViews FollowSymLinks\n\
                AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .py\n\
                AllowOverride All\n\
                Options +ExecCGI\n\
                Require all granted\n\
            </Directory>\n\
            ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log\n\
            LogLevel warn\n\
            CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined\n\
        </VirtualHost>' > /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

RUN a2enmod cgi
RUN service apache2 restart

[...]

EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 8080

ENV PYTHONPATH "${PYTHONPATH}:/var/www/html"
CMD ["uvicorn", "main:app", "--proxy-headers", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "8080"]
```

So basically Apache serves port 80 and the api listens to port 8080.

I got a docker-compose.yaml file that looks like:

```
version: "3.6"
services:
  web:
    build: .
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "8090:80"
      - "8092:8080"
    volumes:
      - ./database/:/var/www/html/database
```

This container runs behind an Apache2 reverse proxy in which I set this:

```
[...]
ProxyPass /server/api http://localhost:8092/server/api
ProxyPassReverse /server/api http://localhost:8092/server/api

ProxyPass /server http://localhost:8090/
ProxyPassReverse /server http://localhost:8090/
[...]
```

The thing is that when everything is started normally, the API works fine, but the main server does not respond, I get the following `proxy_http` error in the host apache logs:

```
AH01102: error reading status line from remote server localhost:8090
```

I checked inside the docker and the apache2 service was not running after starting the docker.
I can solve the problem by running:

```
docker exec -t web-1 service apache2 restart
```

It seems like when the uvicorn command starts, it somehow masks/stops the apache server ?
I don't really know how to fix this since I cannot add a:

```
 RUN service apache2 restart
```

after the last CMD line in the dockerfile.

Comment: I would not recommend running multiple services within one container. You lose many advantages and is not best practice. The Reason for your problem is, that only one process can "own" the container (primary PID or PID 1). If you really want to run multiple process in one container, you need something like supervisord. [Docker documentation about multi service containers](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/multi-service_container/)

Comment: Oooh I see, I didn't think about that, I ended up building two separate docker-compose.yml files and it works, but i will try your way, thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the suggestions of @Spirit I changed the docker-compose in order to setup 2 services with 2 separate Dockerfiles, there is now no more issues with ports:

```
version: "3.6"
services:
  web:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "8090:80"
    volumes:
      - ./database:/var/www/html/database
  
  api:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-api
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "8092:80"
    volumes:
      - ./database:/var/www/html/database
```